why there is wrong data from lognorm.fit?
I wrote code to get distribution for lognorm from 8 data and I got 8 graph. Just one of them look like having some problem(don't fit well to histogram) and the parameter from lognorm.fit is so different with others even their mean and std is quite same.
wrong one enter image description here
good one [enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/dA9nT.png
for i in range(8):
plt.figure()
num_bins=60
y_hist, bins_hist, p_hist=plt.hist(data_of_5years[i],bins=num_bins, density=True, label = 'Normalized fit')
bins_hist_mid=bins_hist[:-1]+(np.diff(bins_hist)[0])/2
x = bins_hist_mid.copy()

shape_param_logn, loc_param_logn, scale_param_logn=stats.lognorm.fit(data_of_5years[i])

pdf_fitted_logn= stats.lognorm.pdf(x, shape_param_logn, loc=loc_param_logn, scale = scale_param_logn)
plt.plot(x, pdf_fitted_logn, '-k', label = 'Lognormal pdf_fitted')

I tried to calculate mean and std of each data[0] to data[7] and there was no problem.
But why the parameter from data [3] is so different from others even other values are quite similar?

Data points below or equal 0? This would mess lognormal
